# Provisioning services in Linux Centos 6 with Ansible or Terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Well, I have a client with an intranet infrastructure, that can't be accessed by the internet or VPN, so I need to access through TeamViewer.

This client gave me 10 VMs (Linux Centos 6) to work (can't create others or destroy it). So I need to prepare this infrastructure to run my CI/CD and deliver the software, then I need these services running before my software deploy:

1. Docker
2. Mongo DB
3. Postgres
4. Nginx
5. Jenkins

I'm thinking about two options to solve it:

1. TerraformCLI (remember I will need to access client through Teamviewer and run `terraform apply`)
2. Ansible (Here I can list the 10 machines and execute all together with 1 playbook).

I heard about **Terraform** is more to provision Servers (VM, EC2 ...), VPC, Subnet, LoadBalancers, but **Ansible** is more about configuring each machine, in a more granular way. If this is correct I think Ansible is the correct choice for me.

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Terraform provision your environment from scratch. It is a Infrastructure as Code tool.

Ansible configures your environment. It is a configuration management tool.

Often, people combine both of them. First provision the network stack, servers using Terraoform and then configure the applications inside the servers using Ansible.

You already have the VMs hence opting for configuration management tool(Chef, Ansible, Puppet, Salt Stack) better fits your use case.

Comment: Cool, but in some areas Terraform and Ansible conflicts. For instance, I can use Ansible to install MongoDB as a docker image and Terraform can do it also. But I understand that more correct is use Ansible in this case, because is more a "configuration" then  Infrastructure subject. right ?